# How should I connect a new ceiling fan to my wiring?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I’m looking to replace my original light (2 bulbs) with a fan and light assembly. Once I removed the old light cover, I came across this wiring and it kind of threw me for a loop.

The fan requires a connection of the white wire from the ceiling, the receiver as well as the fan itself…However, the three white wires were bundled into one connection, which means there would be a total of 6 wires in that connection.

I do not have any ground wires, only the black and white.

There is also another bundle of wires connected together, including a black wire. Should I just be connecting the fan to the bundle of white, and the black with the black, leaving the other bundle of wires alone?

original wiring

[image: original wiring]

Comment: Do not remove any wires till we see the picture/s.  Most times you can connect new the exact same way as the old.  Might need to get the next size wire nut/wago connector.  Ground is only good for safety, not to make stuff work.  Might have ground if you have metal conduit, instead of wires in cable.

Comment: Can we see that other bundle of wires?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Black and white wires crossed in the ceiling](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/102082/black-and-white-wires-crossed-in-the-ceiling)

Comment: Or this? [Ceiling box has 2 black wires and 1 white wire](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/179512/ceiling-box-has-2-black-wires-and-1-white-wire)

Comment: Or this? [Why is there a white wire connected to multiple black wires in my light box?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/117047/why-is-there-a-white-wire-connected-to-multiple-black-wires-in-my-light-box)

Answer (score 1):

A photo before you disconnected the old lamp would have been helpful. So would a picture that shows the other wires in the box. Without that or measurements I'm guessing.

But if all the white wires were connected together, add the lamp's white wire and connect all four together (you may need a larger wire nut), then connect the lamp's black wire to the unconnected black wire with another wire nut, and I'd give that 95% odds of being correct.

Basically,you just want to unplug one lamp and plug in a new one. So  connect the new fixture exactly the way the old fixture was connected, make sure you don't change anything else, and if that worked this should work.